# Hadoop Fair Scheduler Queue assignment

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

I am implementing Fair Scheduler to manage pyspark jobs in the cluster. However, I do not understand how jobs are assigned to pools in Fair Scheduler.

For eg, in my current cluster I have Queues 1..10, there are jobs running in Queues 1,2,3,4 and other queues are empty. Now, if I launch a job to run in a Free Queue(say 10), I expect it to be in running mode as the queue is free. But it is stuck in Waiting mode.

All the pools have Fair scheduling policy  and fairSharePreemptionTimeout is set to 30 seconds. This is the entry in fair-scheduler.xml

```
 `<fairSharePreemptionTimeout>30</fairSharePreemptionTimeout>`
```

Should I be adding any addl entry into fair-scheduler.xml to get the queues pick up jobs fast.

Just a screen shot of my resource manager - 
[image: s]

Comment: When submitting jobs do you submit them to different queues or do you define the < queuePlacementPolicy> in your fair-scheduler allocation XML?

Comment: I do that but even then, jobs added to free Queues would not get into running until the older jobs in active Queues are over.

Comment: Any inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose without your fair scheduler XML file.